# How can I change system.timespan format VB.net?

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have the following code VB.net/asp.net:

```
Dim DT As Date = date value
Dim DIF As System.TimeSpan = DT.Subtract(Date.Now)
TextBox1.Text = DIF.ToString
```

But the output format is dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ms:nanoseconds, like 10/07/2012 04:53:11.2812500. But I need the output to be like 10/07/2012 04:53.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at

[TimeSpan.ToString Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx#Y0)

[Standard TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx)

[Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx)